Does strong convergence of operators imply pointwise convergence of their unbounded inverses?
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $A_n:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be a sequence of  bounded linear operators converging strongly to the identity operator, that is, one has
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\|A_nh-h\|=0$$
for all $h \in \mathcal{H}$.
Assume further that $A_n$ are injective and have a common range $\mathcal{R}$ which is dense in $\mathcal{H}$ so that inverses $A_n^{-1}$ are densely defined, possibly unbounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$.
My question is: Is it true that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\|A_n^{-1}h-h\|=0$$
for all $h \in \mathcal{R}$? If not, are there some "natural" additional conditions that guarantee that this is true?
EDIT: If the operators $A_n^{-1}$ happen to be bounded, then by the uniform boundedness principle,  it is necessary to assume in addition that $A_n^{-1}$ are also uniformly bounded in order to have the required convergence. What I'm interested in is the case when $A_n^{-1}$  are unbounded and a possible analogue of the additional uniform boundedness assumption in this situation.
EDIT 2: I'm willing to relax the condition on $\mathcal{R}$ as follows: I'm looking for additional assumption that guarantees that there exists a dense subset $\widetilde{\mathcal{R}}$ of $\mathcal{H}$ contained in the ranges of $A_n$ (which now may even be different) such that the convergence of $A_n^{-1}$ holds pointwise on $\widetilde{\mathcal{R}}$.

Would you find a condition that is very similar in spirits to uniform boundedness of the inverses, but that is only equivalent to the weaker assertion that $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ weakly useful?

@DavidGao : Yes, that may be useful. I also relaxed the convergence that I need in the question, see EDIT 2.

Ok. I also have a version that does work for the relaxed condition, though it is a bit overly technical.

We first consider the relaxation that $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ only weakly, instead of in norm. Under the slightly stronger condition that not only $A_n \to 1$ strongly but also $A_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly, the necessary and sufficient condition is that the inverses of $A_n$ are uniformly bounded relative to $A_1^{-1}$ (or $A_m^{-1}$, for any fixed $m$). Indeed, we have the following:
Proposition: Let $(A_n)_n$ be a sequence of injective operators with a shared dense range $\mathcal{R}$, $A_n \to 1$ and $A_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly. Fix $m_0 > 0$. TFAE,

For any $m > 0$, $\{A_n^{-1}\}_n$ is uniformly bounded relative to $A_m^{-1}$, i.e., for any $m > 0$, there exists $C > 0$ (which can depend on $m$) s.t. $\sup_n \|A_n^{-1}h\| \leq C\|A_m^{-1}h\|$ for all $h \in \mathcal{R}$;
$\{A_n^{-1}\}_n$ is uniformly bounded relative to $A_{m_0}^{-1}$, i.e., there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\sup_n \|A_n^{-1}h\| \leq C\|A_{m_0}^{-1}h\|$ for all $h \in \mathcal{R}$;
For any $h \in \mathcal{R}$, $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ weakly;
For any $h \in \mathcal{R}$, $\sup_n \|A_n^{-1}h\| < \infty$.

Lemma: Let $A_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly and $h_n \in H$ be a sequence of vectors that converges weakly to $0$. Then $A_nh_n \to 0$ weakly.
Proof: Since $h_n \to 0$ weakly, they are uniformly bounded, i.e., there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\|h_n\| \leq C$ for all $n$. Now, let $k \in H$. Then, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N > 0$ s.t. $\|A_n^\ast k - k\| < \epsilon$ and $|\langle k, h_n \rangle| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$. Thus, when $n \geq N$,
$$|\langle k, A_nh_n \rangle| = |\langle A_n^\ast k, h_n \rangle| \leq \|A_n^\ast k - k\|\|h_n\| + |\langle k, h_n \rangle| < C\epsilon + \epsilon = (C + 1)\epsilon$$
Since $k \in H$ and $\epsilon > 0$ are arbitrary, this implies $A_nh_n \to 0$ weakly. $\square$
Proof of Proposition: $(1 \Rightarrow 2)$ Obvious.
$(2 \Rightarrow 3)$ As there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\|A_n^{-1}h\| \leq C\|A_{m_0}^{-1}h\|$ for all $h \in \mathcal{R}$, we have, for all $k \in H$,
$$\|A_n^{-1}A_{m_0}k\| \leq C\|A_{m_0}^{-1}A_{m_0}k\| = C\|k\|$$
Thus, $\sup_n \|A_n^{-1}A_{m_0}\| < \infty$. Now, let $h \in \mathcal{R}$. We may choose $k \in H$ s.t. $h = A_{m_0}k$. Then $(A_n^{-1}h)_n = (A_n^{-1}A_{m_0}k)_n$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of vectors, so there exists a subsequence $(A_{n_l}^{-1}h)_l$ which converges weakly to some $h' \in H$, i.e., $A_{n_l}^{-1}h - h' \to 0$ weakly. By Lemma, we have,
$$h - A_{n_l}h' = A_{n_l}(A_{n_l}^{-1}h - h') \to 0$$
weakly. Thus, $A_{n_l}h' \to h$ weakly. But $A_{n_l} \to 1$ strongly, so $A_{n_l}h' \to h'$ in norm. Thus, $h' = h$, so $A_{n_l}^{-1}h \to h$ weakly. Note that the same argument shows, for any subsequence of $(A_n^{-1}h)_n$, there exists a further subsequence that converges weakly to $h$. Thus, $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ weakly.
$(3 \Rightarrow 4)$ Obvious by uniform boundedness principle.
$(4 \Rightarrow 1)$ The assumption implies $\|\cdot\|_\infty = \sup_n \|A_n^{-1} \cdot\|$ is a norm on $\mathcal{R}$. Using boundedness of $A_n$, it is not hard to check this norm makes $\mathcal{R}$ into a Banach space. Similarly, for a fixed $m > 0$, the norm $\|\cdot\|_m = \|A_m^{-1} \cdot\|$ makes $\mathcal{R}$ into a Banach space as well. Since $\|\cdot\|_m \leq \|\cdot\|_\infty$, $(\mathcal{R}, \|\cdot\|_\infty) \to (\mathcal{R}, \|\cdot\|_m)$ is a bijective bounded linear map. By open mapping theorem, we therefore have, there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\|\cdot\|_\infty \leq C\|\cdot\|_m$, i.e., $\sup_n \|A_n^{-1}h\| \leq C\|A_m^{-1}h\|$ for all $h \in \mathcal{R}$. $\square$
There is a way to ensure $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ in norm on a dense subspace $\mathcal{R}_0 \subset \mathcal{R}$ as well. One way to do this is to assume $A_nA_n^\ast$ between different $n$ also have the same range $\mathcal{R}_0$. We note that, as $A_n$ has dense range, $A_n^\ast$ is injective, so $A_nA_n^\ast$ is injective and positive, whence it has dense range as well. Thus, $\mathcal{R}_0$ is a dense subspace of $\mathcal{R}$. Now, we can impose uniform boundedness of $\{(A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}\}_n$ relative to $(A_{m_0}A_{m_0}^\ast)^{-1}$ (on $\mathcal{R}_0$, of course). If we again have both $A_n \to 1$ and $A_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly, by uniform boundedness principle, $\{A_n\}_n$ and $\{A_n^\ast\}_n$ are uniformly bounded, so as multiplication is strongly continuous on bounded sets, $A_nA_n^\ast \to 1$. Hence, by Proposition, $(A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}h \to h$ weakly for all $h \in \mathcal{R}_0$. Moreover, we observe that, for any $h \in \mathcal{R}_0$, we may write $h = A_nA_n^\ast k_n$ for some $k_n \in H$, so,
$$\langle h, (A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}h \rangle = \langle A_nA_n^\ast k_n, k_n \rangle = \langle A_n^\ast k_n, A_n^\ast k_n \rangle = \|A_n^{-1}h\|^2$$
So $\sup_n \|(A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}h\| \leq C\|(A_{m_0}A_{m_0}^\ast)^{-1}h\|$ for all $h \in \mathcal{R}_0$ implies,
$$\sup_n \|A_n^{-1}h\|^2 \leq \|h\|\sup_n \|(A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}h\| \leq C\|h\|\|(A_{m_0}A_{m_0}^\ast)^{-1}h\|$$
For the proof of $(2 \Rightarrow 3)$ direction of the Proposition, one may check that $(A_n^{-1}h)_n$ being uniformly bounded is enough to imply $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ weakly. Thus, the above condition implies $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ weakly for all $h \in \mathcal{R}_0$. We also note that, as $(A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}h \to h$ weakly,
$$\|A_n^{-1}h\|^2 = \langle h, (A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}h \rangle \to \langle h, h \rangle = \|h\|^2$$
i.e., $\|A_n^{-1}h\| \to \|h\|$. Coupled with $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ weakly, this implies $A_n^{-1}h \to h$ in norm. Thus, we obtain the following result,
Proposition: Let $(A_n)_n$ be a sequence of injective operators with a shared dense range $\mathcal{R}$, $A_n \to 1$ and $A_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly. Let $(A_nA_n^\ast)_n$ have shared range $\mathcal{R}_0$ as well. Then $A_nA_n^\ast$ are all injective operators with dense ranges, so $(A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}$ are well-defined. Fix $m_0 > 0$. Assume,

$\{(A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}\}_n$ is uniformly bounded relative to $(A_{m_0}A_{m_0}^\ast)^{-1}$, i.e., there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\sup_n \|(A_nA_n^\ast)^{-1}h\| \leq C\|(A_{m_0}A_{m_0}^\ast)^{-1}h\|$ for all $h \in \mathcal{R}_0$.

Then $\|A_n^{-1}h - h\| \to 0$ for all $h \in \mathcal{R}_0$.
Remark: As a technical matter, one doesn't really need $(A_n)_n$ sharing a dense range $\mathcal{R}$ in the proposition above anymore. As long as they are all injective and have dense ranges, and $(A_nA_n^\ast)_n$ all share range $\mathcal{R}_0$ (and, of course, we still need $A_n \to 1$ and $A_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly), the above proposition holds.

Very nice. Thank you.

The answer is no also in the case of unbounded operators $A_n^{-1}.$
Let $A_n$ act on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ by $$ (A_nx)_k=\begin{cases}x_k & k< n\\  4^{-n}x_n & k=n\\ 2^{-k}x_k & k>n+1\end{cases}$$ Then $A_n$ are injective and $A_n\to I$ strongly. Moreover $$R(A_n)=D(A_n^{-1})=\left\{x\,:\, \sum 4^{k}|x_k|^2<\infty \right\}$$ and $$ (A_n^{-1}x)_k=\begin{cases}x_k & k< n\\  4^{n}x_n & k=n\\ 2^{k}x_k & k>n+1\end{cases}$$ The range of $A_n$ is dense as it contains all sequences with finitely many nonzero terms.
We have $v=\{3^{-k}\}\in D(A_n).$  However $$(A_n^{-1}v)_n=4^n3^{-n}\to \infty$$ Hence $\|A_n^{-1}v\|\to \infty.$ Therefore $A_n^{-1}v$ is not convergent.

Thank you. It's curious though that $A_n^{-1}$ converge on the sequences with finite support. Do you think that's always the case under the conditions of the question when $\mathcal{H}=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ ?

The answer is no. In the following example operators $A_n$ are invertible and positive definite. It does not seem realistic that there are general conditions for this to hold besides uniform boundedness of the inverses.
Let $\mathcal H = \ell^2(\mathbb N)$ (the seperable hilbert space of square-summable sequences) and consider a bounded sequence $\lambda = \{\lambda_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$. By $D_\lambda$ we denote the corresponding diagonal operator $D_\lambda x = \lambda x = \{\lambda_n x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$. Clearly for bounded $\lambda$ the diagonal operator $D_\lambda$ is bounded.
Let $A_n = D_\lambda$, where $\lambda = \{\lambda_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ is defined by the following rule:
$$
\lambda_k = \begin{cases} 1, & k < n \\ 1/n^2, & k \ge n\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $A_n$ is a bounded and invertible operator (the inverse is everywhere defined and bounded, so $\mathcal R = \mathcal H$). Also, clearly, $A_n$ strongly converges to $I$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Finally, consider $x \in \mathcal R$, such that $x = \{x_k = 1/k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$. It is easy to see that $\|A_n^{-1}x\| \ge n$, in particular $A_n^{-1} x \nrightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Thank for this example but in general, by the uniform boundedness principle,  if $A_n^{-1}$ are bounded but not uniformly bounded, they cannot converge strongly to 1. What I'm really interested is the case when $A_n^{-1}$ are unbounded and a possible analogue of the uniform boundedness condition in this situation. Perhaps I didn't make this clear enough in the question, so I will edit and add that.
